# If I put List<Child> into an Intent, then I retrieve List<Parent> from the other Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, extends

These are my model classes:

```
public class Animal implements Parcelable{   
//parcelable implementation
}

public class Cat extends Animal {   
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
}
```

I want to pass an `Array` of Animal from an `Activity` to another using `Intent.putExtra(String name, Parcelable [] value)`.

So I do this:

```
List<Animal> animals = new Array[3];
animals[0] = new Dog();
animals[1] = new Cat();
animals[2] = new Dog();

Intent.putExtra("myAnimals", animals ).
```

When I try to retrieve the array from the other `Activity` with:

```
Parcelable[] p = (Parcelable[])data.getParcelableArrayExtra("myAnimals");
```

I **DON'T** get an array like this:

```
[0]Dog
[1]Cat
[2]Dog
```

I get an array like this:

```
[0]Animal
[1]Animal
[2]Animal
```

I don't understand If my logic is incorrect or when you pass an `Array` like mine to an `Intent` it is turned into an array of `SuperClass` objects.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create a `CREATOR` field in every of your subclass, e.g.

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Cat> CREATOR
         = new Parcelable.Creator<Cat>() {
     public Cat createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new Cat(in);
     }

     public Cat[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Cat[size];
     }
 };
```

Probably you only have this field in your base class `Animal`, so when Android tries to recreate the objects from `Parcelable` it can only call the `CREATOR` of `Animal`, so all your objects are `Animals`.